# A Robot should stop moving If cmd_vel is stopped Publishing or If STOP command send

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I have one confusion
I am publishing cmd_vel ( geometry_msgs/Twist ) messages using teleop_twist_keyboard .
The Robot subscribes this messages i.e cmd_vel  message.
When should my robot stop moving ?
a) As soon as I stop sending or publishing the cmd_vel from the Keyboard
OR
b) It should stop moving If i send him a STOP command
Please can anyone Suggest which one is the Right ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241695/a-robot-should-stop-moving-if-cmd_vel-is-stopped-publishing-or-if-stop-command-send./) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-16**:
You've updated this without providing any additional info; it looks like you're trying to gather additional answers. Is there something that was unclear or not satisfying about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For safety, most robots use the first option (a), with a timeout.

If the ROS node that receives /cmd_vel doesn't receive a message within a certain time period, it brings the robot to a stop. I'd recommend a 1 to 2 second timeout for most indoor robots

The timeout ensures that if the connection to teleop is lost, or an autonomous navigation node stops sending commands, the robot comes to a stop instead of driving into a wall or other obstacle.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2016-08-16**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-11**:
I have the similar questions.. just wondering if anybody has some implementation that can be refer to?